# How to Export HTML to Document without border or colored text

Tags: javascript, html, css, download, ms-word

I want to create an editable text where you fill the contentEditable area and export the text result as document and I found a script online to that and I modify it but the problem i faced is that the contentEditable area is not visible it appears like fixed text until you click on it so I made a black border and red text for the contentEditable area so the user can see it but when I export the document it has black border and red text so How can i make them visible when you fill text and disappear when you export the document this [my website](https://testiiiiiiiiiiiitest.blogspot.com/2019/05/html-to-document.html) that was inspired by this
 [site](http://www.parchance.fr/contrat-travail/) and this the script [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/talabe/g6w07sad/)

```js
function Export2Doc(element, filename = ''){
    var preHtml = "<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'><head><meta charset='utf-8'><title>Export HTML To Doc</title></head><body>";
    var postHtml = "</body></html>";
    var html = preHtml+document.getElementById(element).innerHTML+postHtml;

    var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', html], {
        type: 'application/msword'
    });
    
    // Specify link url
    var url = 'data:application/vnd.ms-word;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(html);
    
    // Specify file name
    filename = filename?filename+'.doc':'document.doc';
    
    // Create download link element
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    
    if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob ){
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
    }else{
        // Create a link to the file
        downloadLink.href = url;
        
        // Setting the file name
        downloadLink.download = filename;
        
        //triggering the function
        downloadLink.click();
    }
    
    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
}
```

```css
span.a{

display:inline-block;

}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="exportContent">
   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
   Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
   <span  class="a" contenteditable="true" style="min-width:20px;border:1px solid black;color:red">
    when an unknown printer
    </span> took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
   It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. 
   It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
   and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>

<button onclick="Export2Doc('exportContent');">document</button>

</body>
```

Comment: In your `export2Doc` function, you could try removing the style (and then adding it again after it's been downloaded)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the inline style from your editable span `style="min-width:20px;border:1px solid black;color:red"` and put it under the `span.a` selector where you set the display to inline-block.

```js
function Export2Doc(element, filename = ''){
    var preHtml = "<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'><head><meta charset='utf-8'><title>Export HTML To Doc</title></head><body>";
    var postHtml = "</body></html>";
    var html = preHtml+document.getElementById(element).innerHTML+postHtml;

    var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', html], {
        type: 'application/msword'
    });
    
    // Specify link url
    var url = 'data:application/vnd.ms-word;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(html);
    
    // Specify file name
    filename = filename?filename+'.doc':'document.doc';
    
    // Create download link element
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    
    if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob ){
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
    }else{
        // Create a link to the file
        downloadLink.href = url;
        
        // Setting the file name
        downloadLink.download = filename;
        
        //triggering the function
        downloadLink.click();
    }
    
    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
}
```

```css
span.a{
    display:inline-block;
    min-width:20px; 
    border:1px solid black;
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="exportContent">
   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
   Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
   <span  class="a" contenteditable="true">
    when an unknown printer
    </span> took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
   It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. 
   It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
   and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>

<button onclick="Export2Doc('exportContent');">document</button>

</body>
```

Comment: I'm really grateful for your help can you please tell what changes you have made so if I faced this problem is the future I will fix it .Is it just CSS or javascript or both ?

Comment: I've only made CSS changes. Removed the inline style of the editable span element:   `style="min-width:20px;border:1px solid black;color:red"` and put it inside the style sheet: `span.a{
    display:inline-block;
    min-width:20px; 
    border:1px solid black;
    color:red;
}`